# storm not able to start with normclasspath

Tags: apache-storm

Not able to start apache storm.

```
root@localhost ~]# storm nimbus
  File "/home/mahendra/storm/bin/storm", line 51
    normclasspath = cygpath if sys.platform == 'cygwin' else identity
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@localhost ~]#


[root@localhost ~]# python -V
Python 2.7
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my Redhat 6 install on Python 3.4. I changed the hashbag in the `/bin/storm` file from: `#!/usr/bin/python` to: `#!/usr/bin/env python`